# DOS command to move all files in subdirectories one level up

Tags: windows-xp, dos, batch-file

I have a folder with a lot of sub folders with one or more files in each. I am trying to write a batch file that moves all those files to C:\songs (for example). Any help? I have already tried

```
C:\>FOR /R C:\Test %i IN (*) DO MOVE %i C:\Songs
```

The folders Test and songs exist, but I get an error saying

```
%i was unexpected at this time.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FOR /R %i IN (C:\Test\*) DO MOVE "%i" C:\Songs
```

In a batch file, it has to be %%i. Weird quirk of batch.

Comment: Did you run this? For me it just hangs the console.  Weird.

Comment: If the folder's massive, it will take a long time to parse everything recursively. Yes, I did test it, on Win7 and now on XP. Genuine MS-DOS would need \*.\* though.

Comment: For me this moves the files but not the folders. I actually try to move files from subfolder up one level - maybe this affects it. The command is this: 
FOR /R %i IN (.\folder\subfolder\\*) DO MOVE "%i" .\folder\

Answer (score 5):

(move files in sub-directories up 1)

```
for /r %x in (*.*) do move "%x" "%x"/../..
```

(last part I usually use backward slants but this crazy thing kept deleting them for some reason. It'll work either way though)

(delete unneeded directories)

```
for /d /r %x in (bin) do rd "%x"
```

i.e., if you had a bunch of directories with files in "bin" directories under those
and you wanted to move everything up 1 and delete the "bin" directories.

Comment: How would you change the first command to use the selected folder rather than `(*.*)`? (This is for use in a batch file which I will then use with a custom context menu command.)